# How to recover a specific data in the firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have this structure in the database:

[image]

I have a function that return the current user logged

```
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 auth.currentUser.uid;
```

And i want to retrieve "requisicoes" when "idUser" ==  `auth.currentUser.uid;`

Basically, the user retrieves the requests created by himself.

That's my StreamBuilder

```
final _controller = StreamController<QuerySnapshot>.broadcast();
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> addListenersRequests() {
final stream = db
    .collection("requisicoes")
    .where("usuario.idUser", isEqualTo: idUsuarioLogado)
    .snapshots();


stream.listen((dados) {
  _controller.add(dados);
});
return null;
```

}

Note: `idUsuarioLogado` is returning correctly currentUser

The problem is that I am getting everything in the "requisicoes" collection, when I create a new user, other users' requests appear on the screen

is there a logic problem in StreamBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here [Firestore is ignoring the where clause in the query in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63991432/firestore-is-ignoring-the-where-clause-in-the-query-in-flutter)

My example is the same as the link above, I have two functions, one `addListenersRequests()` and the other `getCurrentUser()`, these two functions I was calling in the initState method, the problem is that getCurrentUser is async, so addListenersRequests () was being executed first, before the value of the variable idUsuarioLogado is filled.

So I merged the two functions into one, so that getCurrentUser can be executed first

Final code:

```
Future<StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>> addListenersRequests() async{

await getDataUser();

final stream = db
    .collection("requisicoes")
    .where("usuario.idUser", isEqualTo: idUsuarioLogado)
    .snapshots();

stream.listen((dados) {
  _controller.add(dados);
});
return null;
```

}

Now it is working correctly.

The strange thing about this story is that the firebase executes the clause and retrieves everything in the collection even when the referenced variable is null

Answer (score 0):

As per you problem ,I think you are fetching the data of your current logged **uid** .But You want to retrieve the details of particulers **users** created(i,e **documendId**) . Then you have to fetch **documentId** first.Like

```
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream:users.snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            if(!snapshot.hasData){
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
              return  Center(
                child: Container(
                  width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.5,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/5,
                  child:  Text(document.id),

                ),
              );
            }).toList());
          }),
```

You have to fetch **document.id**. This is your particuler user instead of  this.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 auth.currentUser.uid;
```

***Note**: This will return you current logged **userId**.*

For more details gothrough this[link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rahul, actually i want fetching the data of  current logged uid. I'm not sure, because I haven't looked at this project for a while, but I remember that I retrive for the data correctly

Comment: For you to have a better idea of the app, it is an app to make reports, when a user creates a new report, I am associating the field "idUser" with your current logged uid

Comment: Then...is there an error particularly in this clause? .where("usuario.idUser", isEqualTo: idUsuarioLogado)

Comment: @LucasBaggio I understand your problem . I study your code .I found no error.

Comment: @LucasBaggio Please downgrade your firestore packege  in puspec and try again. Like cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1    . I was getting same type of issues in latest versions on StreamBuilder.

Comment: And follow this link https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228737/discussion-between-lucas-baggio-and-rahul-kushwaha).